# Is it possible to fetch the hidden info in webpage using python requests(?srn=true) library?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

Here is the url
"https://www.gumtree.com/p/sofas/dfs-couches.-two-3-seaters.-one-teal-and-one-green.-pink-storage-footrest.-less-than-2-years-old.-/1265932994"

Login details : 
usrname : life@tech69.com
pwd : shiva@123

While opening the page with above credentials, we can get the info like
Contact details
0770228XXXX

However if adding the ?srn = true at the end of url will give the following info
(https://www.gumtree.com/p/sofas/dfs-couches.-two-3-seaters.-one-teal-and-one-green.-pink-storage-footrest.-less-than-2-years-old.-/1265932994?srn=true)

Contact details
07702287887

The code I've used is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = requests.session()
login_data = dict(email='life@tech69.com', password='shiva@123')
s.post('https://my.gumtree.com/login', data=login_data)
r = s.get('https://www.gumtree.com/p/sofas/dfs-couches.-two-3-seaters.-one-teal-and-one-green.-pink-storage-footrest.-less-than-2-years-old.-/1265932994?srn=true')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
y = soup.find('strong' , 'txt-large txt-emphasis form-row-label').text
print str(y)
```

However the above python code still giving the partial info as 
0770228XXXX
How to fetch the full info using python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that site is protected by recaptcha, a technology that is specifically designed to prevent autologins

so the line `s.post('https://my.gumtree.com/login', data=login_data)`

results in this

[image]

so when you try to go to the other url you are not actually logged in, and it will not reveal the number...

there may be ways to circumvent this, but im not sure of any offhand...

Comment: Yes, Joran thanks for the info I'll try to Bypass the captcha